how to remove welcome sentence on powershell, oh-my-posh
In this picture I highlight the part, so you can see what exactly I tried to remove.
My problem connected with oh-my-posh

I tried to find solution online but I couldn't because I do not know what exactly to search and I hope you can help me with this problem.

How does this not work? Please let us know what you have tried and what does not work.

If you follow the migration guide properly, the message should be gone.
